# ApexApplication:Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user

Tags: apex, trigger, class

We are getting this error:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user

When we are performing insertion trying to update contact or user object where in user is inactive.

Please check below class and help us to avoid the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard Salesforce functionality to not allow inactive users to create new record in System.

Any reason specific reason why you are trying to insert new record with inactive user.

Activating the user will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Database class to insert or update any contact or user record.
Insert using following code --

```
Database.SaveResult[] insertResult = Database.insert(<UserList/ContactList>, false);
```

Update using following code

```
Database.SaveResult[] unsertResult = Database.update(<UserList/ContactList>, false);
```

You can view errors using following code -

```
for(Database.SaveResult rs : insertResult/unsertResult){
       if(!rs.isSuccess()){
            Database.Error emsg=rs.getErrors()[0]; 
            SYSTEM.DEBUG('--ERRORS--'+emsg);
        }
    }
```

This will help inseting or updating valid contact or user records.
Invalid record can be viewed using the resultset code given above.

Comment: Hi@Pramit Kumar. Thank you for your reply .Can you please tell me Exactly where can i use Database.SaveResult in my code.

Comment: Database.Savereult is for your own use to see which records get inserted/updated and which records get failed and reason for their failure.